# Easy monocular camera self-calibration algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, kalman-filter

I have a video of a road/building and I want to create a 3D model out of it. The scene I am looking at is rigid and the drone is moving. I assume not having any extra info like camera pose, accelerations or GPS position. I would love to find a python implementation that I can adapt to my liking.

So far, I have decided to use the OpenCV `calcOpticalFlowFarneback()` for optical flow, which seems reasonably fast and accurate. With it, I can get the Fundamental Matrix F with `findFundamentalMat()`. So far so good.

Now, according to the tutorial I am following [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/02/07/structure-from-motion-and-3d-reconstruction-on-the-easy-in-opencv-2-3-w-code/), I am supposed to magically have the Calibration Matrix of the camera, which I obviously don't have nor plan to have available in the future app I am developing.

After some long research, I have found a paper (*Self-calibration of a moving camera from point correspondences and
fundamental matrices*) from 1997 that defines what I am looking for (with a nice summary [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/FUSIELLO3/node4.html)). I am looking for the simplest/easiest implementation possible, and I am stuck with these problems:

- If the camera I am going to use changes exposure and focus automatically (no zoom), are the intrinsic parameters of the camera going to change?
- I am not familiar with the *Homotopy Continuation Method* for solving equations numerically, plus they seem to be slow.
- I intend to use the *Extended Kalman Filter*, but do not know where to start, knowing that a bad initialization leads to non-convergence.

Digging some more I found a *Multi Camera Self Calibration toolbox* open-source written for Octave with a Python wrapper. My last resort will be to break down the code and write it in Python directly. Any other options?

Note: I do not want to use the a chess board nor the planarity constraint.

Is there any other way to very accurately self-calibrate my camera? After 20 years of research since 1997, has anyone come up with a more straightforward method??

Comment: You probably want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_adjustment

Comment: Update: In a 2017 [survey](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s41074-017-0027-2), I have found a reference to [a paper from 2009](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Javier_Civera/publication/224557479_Camera_Self-Calibration_for_Sequential_Bayesian_Structure_From_Motion/links/00b49517fb09a2f650000000.pdf), as the state of the art of camera self-calibration with a video sequence. The survey also mentions publications that handle camera parameter change as well as removal of camera zooming effect.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-shot thing, or are you developing an app to process lots videos like these automatically?

If the former, I'd rather use an integrated tool like Blender. Look up one of the motion tracking (or "matchmoving") tutorials on youtube to get an idea of it, for example [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY).

Comment: Thanks Francesco. I didn't know tools like Blender existed. Good to know. However, I was aiming for a real depth reconstruction of the scene. According to a paper called *Visual SLAM algorithms: a survey from 2010 to 2016*, which is summarized [here](https://www.kudan.eu/kudan-news/different-types-visual-slam-systems/), I have been able to find what I am looking for. It's a dense direct SLAM method called DTAM ([demo here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df9WhgibCQA))

Comment: In any case, I am still stuck with the self-calibration problem